# When SSMS displays multiple `(1 row(s) affected)`, is there a way to find out more information about the rows affected?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, when I insert, update or delete rows from a table, in the messages board, it shows `(1 row(s) affected)`. However, there are situations where multiple `(1 row(s) affected)` are displayed.

I was just wondering if there is a way to find out more information about the rows affected? like the table it is in? the data that it contains? etc.

[image]

Comment: Hope it is not possible. But you can manually add the `PRINT` statements with your requied data.

Comment: lol i thought everything is possible, but apparently not

Comment: then how do people determine what has changed in their table?

Comment: @Tony.Stark Depending on your query, an OUTPUT clause can work wonders. You can then use an `inserted, deleted.<column_name>` to [see the rows inserted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after each query, you can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to determine number of rows affected.

example :

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';
```